# Specify exact number of decimal places by user input , Java

Tags: java, input, decimal, formatter

I am writing a calculator program, where the user in the last input prompt writes the number of decimal points (1, 2 ,3...), that the output of for example sum of 2 numbers should have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class Lab01 {

    public void start(String[] args) {

        double cislo1;
        double cislo2;
        int operacia;
        String decimal;
        String dec;

        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select operation (1-sum, 2-dev, 3- *, 4- / )");
        operacia = op.nextInt();
        if (operacia >= 1 && operacia <= 4) {
            if(operacia == 1) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter number one:");
                cislo1=input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter number two:");
                cislo2=input.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Enter number of decimal points");
                decimal=input.nextLine();

                dec="%."+decimal+"f";

                Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
                fmt.format(dec, cislo2);
                System.out.println( fmt);
             }
         } else {
             System.out.println("wrong!");
         }
     }
 }
```

I have tried Formatter method for the decimal input but the error says" Conversion = '.' "

```
System.out.println("Enter number of decimal points");
decimal = input.nextLine();
dec = "%." + decimal + "f";
Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
fmt.format(dec, cislo2);              
System.out.println(fmt);
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/JJZT5267).  Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: [Works for me too](https://ideone.com/YuJL41)

Comment: Are you participating in the vertical space awards? Please format your code reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `decimal` should be an int. So you should change the follow lines:

```
String decimal;
```

You should change to:

```
int decimal;
```

And:

```
decimal = input.nextLine();
```

You should change to:

```
decimal = input.nextInt();
```

Or, if you want to keep it as a String, you can add an extra `input.nextLine();` before reading the number of decimals. It occurs because nextLine() consumes the line separator where you are reading your `cislo2` variable and `nextInt()` will only read an int.

Comment: I have tried the first solution but despite the number behind "decimal" variable, it always rounds the decimal points by 6. Even if i set it to 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "number behind decimal" and "rounds points by 6"? What are the inputs and the output?

Comment: If I set "decimal=input.nextInt();" to 1 when the prompt in console appears, and the "cislo2" is 3.412444124, the output will be 3.412444, with 6 decimal points. 
If I set "decimal=input.nextInt();" to 50, the output will be again 3.412444, with 6 decimal points.

Comment: Are you sure you did not change anything else? Because it is working for me. Beside this, I think that if you want to make a sum within your method you should add fmt.format(dec, **cislo1 + cislo2**) as the parameters to your formatter

Comment: Mistake was on my side. Thanks a lot for the help, it is working now :)